# How to open SharePoint Power View Report in Excel 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, business-intelligence, powerview

Is it possible to open Power View report in Excel which is originally created in SharePoint 2013. I need to open Power View report in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a standalone Power View file (.rdlx) on SharePoint then you won't be able to open that in Excel. You can only open it on Sharepoint. You will have to recreate the view in Excel.

Comment: Is there any web based client tool other than SharePoint in which we can display Power View Report?

Comment: Power Views can be standalone .rdlx files on SharePoint or they can live within Excel 2013 (either on the desktop or on SharePoint or in O365 or on a PowerBI for O365 site).

You could also check out the dashboarding in the Power BI Preview site (www.powerbi.com) that has the same functionality as power view but in a different format. This is free while in preview.

Comment: Is it possible to import PowerView report in MS Excel from SharePoint?

Comment: No, you can't move your Power View report (rdlx) from SharePoint into Excel and you cannot convert your Excel Power View into a Power View report (.rdlx).

Comment: You could export to powerpoint and from there copy and paste into Excel: https://eriksvensen.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/use-power-view-report-exported-from-sharepoint-in-excel-excel-powerview/